# Broadcasting Tokens on Different Channels

Tags: antlr, channel

I'm (tentatively) working on a language translation problem where I would like to include the comments in the source code in the translated code.

I'm working through the ANTLR 4 book "The Definitive Aantlr4 Reference" and section 12.1 "Broadcasting Tokens on Different Channels" seems to address this issue.

Unfortunately, when I try this example this it doesn't work! I get the error:

> error(177): Cymbol.g4:59:30: WHITESPACE is not a recognized channel
> name error(177): Cymbol.g4:62:33: COMMENTS is not a recognized channel
> name

A quick search unveils `Antlr` issue #1555, which loses the issue as the tool working correctly.

My question remains, how do I merge the comments with the AST?

TIA

I copied the sample code lexmagic/Cymbol.g4

```
...
WS  :   [ \t\n\r]+ -> channel(WHITESPACE) ;
...
```

and got the error:

> error(177): Cymbol.g4:59:30: WHITESPACE is not a recognized channel
> name error(177): Cymbol.g4:62:33: COMMENTS is not a recognized channel
> name

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the channels you want to used, except for the 2 built-in channels (`DEFAULT` and `HIDDEN`).

At the top of your grammar (before any rule) add a channels block:

```
channels {
    WHITESPACE
}
```

Keep in mind that channels and tokens share the same namespace. You cannot use the same identifier for a channel and a token.